# Definição de classes

Tags: c++, unreal-engine

Quando estudei sobre definir uma classe seria por exemplo assim no header:

```
class Jogador {
    int id;
    std::string nome;
    int vida;

    void setNome();
    std::string getNome();
}
```

Porem estou vendo um pouco sobre unreal engine e me deparei com isso em um dos codigos dela:

```
class UspringArmComponent* CameraBoom;
class UCameraComponent* FollowCamera;
```

Alguem me ajuda entender essa definição?

Comment: Não coloque código como imagem. Coloque sempre código como texto formatado apropriadamente.

Comment: Obrigado. Removi a imagem e coloquei o código em questão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando está a trabalhar com um Engine a primeira coisa que interessa ver é a documentação pois tem coisas importantes para começar, como:

- guias
- exemplos
- tutoriais
- primeiros passos
- explicação de determinados componentes
- funcionalidades disponiveis

Para o Unreal Engine 4 pode consultar a [documentação aqui](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/).

Em relação às duas linhas de código que indicou (tome cuidado que o `s` em `Spring` tem de ser maiusculo):

```
class USpringArmComponent* CameraBoom;
class UCameraComponent* FollowCamera;
```

Você está a criar dois campos na classe, que são dois ponteiros. Isto seria semelhante a fazer:

```
Jogador* jog;
```

Que iria criar um ponteiro para a classe `Jogador` chamado `jog`, mas sem a palavra reservada `class`. Ela foi usada para fazer a declaração também, normalmente chamada de *forward declaration*. Dessa forma consegue utilizar o ponteiro mesmo sem ter interpretado previamente a definição da classe através do seu header.

Para finalizar as classes em causa tem o seguinte significado:

- `UCameraComponent` - Representa um ponto de vista da camera, contemplando tipo de projeção, angulo de visão e algumas configurações. Esta classe deriva de `USceneComponent`.
- `USpringArmComponent` - Este componente tenta manter os seus filhos a uma distância fixa dos pais, mas irá recolher os filhos se houver uma colisão e voltar a expandir case não haja. Também deriva da classe `USceneComponent`.

Documentação relevante para estas classes:

- [`USceneComponent`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USceneComponent/index.html)
- [`UCameraComponent`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Camera/UCameraComponent/index.html)
- [`USpringArmComponent`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/USpringArmComponent/)